# Visual Composer - vertical_separator not working (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I am trying to create a vertical separator in-between a 2 column list. Basically I want to use the already built-in horizontal separator, vertically.

Have tried the following

```
.vertical_separator > .wpb_wrapper { border-right: 1px solid #f7f7f7; }
```

Comment: what is an issue here?

Comment: Nothing is showing. I tried the solutions above for trying to create a vertical separator (in the same style as the built in horizontal separator)